# TypeError with Python DEAP mutFlipBit

Tags: python, genetic-programming, mutation, deap

I'm writing my first evolutionary algorithm with DEAP.
Everything is working, but the MultiFlipBit mutation operator.
When I attempt to mutate a Tree (Individual), I get the following error:

```
File "Genetic_Programming.py", line 92, in main
    halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    offspring = varOr(population, toolbox, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb)
File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py", line 235, in varOr
    ind, = toolbox.mutate(ind)
File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap/tools/mutation.py", line 132, in mutFlipBit
    individual[i] = type(individual[i])(not individual[i])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Here is the code:

```
pset = gp.PrimitiveSet("MAIN", 8)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.and_, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.or_, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.xor, 2)
pset.addPrimitive(operator.not_, 1)

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", gp.PrimitiveTree, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("expr", gp.genGrow, pset=pset, min_=1, max_=8)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.expr)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
toolbox.register("compile", gp.compile, pset=pset)

def evalSymbReg(individual):
    # Transform the tree expression in a callable function
    print individual
    ind = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)
    # Evaluate the mean squared error between the expression
    # and the real function : x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x
    performance=Genetic_V0.genetic_backtest(ind)
    return performance,

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalSymbReg)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=50)
toolbox.register("mate", gp.cxOnePoint)
#toolbox.register("expr_mut", gp.genGrow, min_=1, max_=4)
#toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, expr=toolbox.expr_mut, pset=pset)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.95)

def main():
    nu=50 
    pop = toolbox.population(n=nu)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(3)

    stats_fit = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats_size = tools.Statistics(len)
    mstats = tools.MultiStatistics(fitness=stats_fit, size=stats_size)
    mstats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    mstats.register("std", numpy.std)
    mstats.register("min", numpy.min)
    mstats.register("max", numpy.max)
    pop, log = algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, nu/2, nu/2, 0.85, 0.15, 200,stats=mstats,
                                   halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    # print log
    return pop, log, hof

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

python version: 2.7

EDITED:
After a suggestion on how solving the problem, I've added to the DEAP mutation library a couple of "print" to better understand what is happening. Here is the same error, as per original question, but with some extra information:

```
individual is  not_(ARG7)
individual[i] is  <deap.gp.Primitive object at 0x10746c158>
(not individual[i]) is  False
type(individual[i]) is  <class 'deap.gp.Primitive'>
type(individual[i])(not individual[i]) is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Genetic_Programming.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "Genetic_Programming.py", line 92, in main
    halloffame=hof, verbose=True)
  File "/Users/giorgio/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py", line 317, in eaMuPlusLambda
    offspring = varOr(population, toolbox, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb)
  File "/Users/giorgio/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py", line 235, in varOr
    ind, = toolbox.mutate(ind)
  File "/Users/giorgio/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap/tools/mutation.py", line 136, in mutFlipBit
    print "type(individual[i])(not individual[i]) is ", type(individual[i])(not individual[i])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Thanks again for any contributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is complaining that you are trying to use a `deap.tools.mutFlipBit` function as a mutator on a indivual that is instance of `deap.gp.PrimitiveTree`. From the docs of [mutFlipBit](http://deap.readthedocs.org/en/master/api/tools.html#deap.tools.mutFlipBit):

> The *individual* is expected to be a sequence and the values of the attributes shall stay valid after the *not* operator is called on them.

So if the code decided to mutate the element `i` of `individual`, it is trying to evaluate `deap.dp.Primitive(not ind[i])`. And the error complains that the constructor of `Primitive` takes 4 arguments, `self, name, args, ret` instead of the passed `self, (not ind[1])`.

The cause of the error is twofold,

1. A `mutBitFlip` mutator is being a **applied to an individual that consists of a list of both "symbolic values" and "operators"**, instead of a list of booleans as expected. So the code could try to negate an operator, e.g. fliping an *and*, which is not defined. However, the code will produce `False` because an object is evaluated to `True` in a boolean context, and will end up trying to create a new `Primitive` from a single argument which is a boolean value.
2. Even if `mutFlipBit` function could discriminate between a [`Primitive`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/api/gp.html#deap.gp.Primitive) and a [`Terminal`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/api/gp.html#deap.gp.Terminal), and would only try to negate `Terminal`s, `deap` will use *symbolic* terminals, because the primary target of a `PrimitiveTree` is not to find a single expressions equivalent to a value (i.e. constant), but rather a expressions, with arguments, equivalent to a function.

You should revisit what are you trying to evolve, an expression that maps to a boolean equation or a set of arguments to a boolean function. And based on that redesign your code.

INITIAL ANSWER:

Your code is not complete, since the line `offspring = varOr(population, toolbox, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb)` is not shown.

However, the problem is caused by the type of one of your invidivuals in your `population` variable. The code is assuming that your individuals are a list of booleans, so the code `individual[i] = type(individual[i])(not individual[i])` would work:

```
x = True
print type(x)(not x)  # Equivalent of bool(True) => False
```

The error says that, `type(individual[i])` got the **init** of a class which expects 3 arguments, e.g. `self` + other 3 arguments.

Comment: Hi memoselyk, thanks for the answer. the varOr is part of one of the standard DEAP algorithms: eaMuPlusLambda.

Comment: I was not able to sort out the problem, but I'm not sure I've understood your suggestion. I've edited my question to include further results and provide some hints on the problem. Please have a look at it. Many thanks again and apologies if I haven't understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @InterceptK, Thanks, the source of the `varOr` was missing in the first traceback, but things are now more clear...

Comment: thanks for the new answer. I've used 'gp.mutUniform' and now is running. I'll check the results and if there something weird, I'll let you know! thanks again for the help.